# How can I re-authenticate a user already signed in under an Okta application using Java?

Tags: java, saml, okta

I have an application that is already working with Okta SAML, but I have a situation, required by the FDA, that in certain process, I need to create a pop-up window with Java Code (I am using OKTA SAML Toolkit 2.0.5) and request the user again their password and send it to Okta to validate.

But I am not sure which tools to use from the toolkit. Can you please point out an example?

The application is running on WebSphere V9.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it not just a case of taking the user details from the pop up and making an authentication request against the Okta api?

Comment: Have you tried asking this question on the Okta dev forums?

Comment: Thank you I will explore the option to connect to Okta API, didn't know about this feature. I am new to this :)

Comment: Hi, I have been struggling on how to do the REST POST call to the Okta endpoint, for example, I was trying to use this function:

Client client = Clients.builder()
   .setOrgUrl("https://myURL.com")
   .setClientCredentials(new TokenClientCredentials("SomeAPIkey"))
   .build();

And then:

client.authenticate(“user”, “password”, “RelayState”, “stateHandler”);

From these project:
https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-java

But I am having issues big time resolving the dependencies in Eclipse.

Is there an easier way to do that? or another Java project I could use?

Comment: What error are you getting?  Its been awhile since I used Eclipse, so I cant give specific help on that.  How are you importing the okta-auth-java library into your project?  The easiest way in this case is to use Maven or Gradle, the instructions for adding the dependency to your pom/build file are on the page.
I was looking at Okta as part of a tutorial on Micronaut, so my knowledge is fairly shallow.

Comment: I downloaded the .zip file, and also from several projects from https://github.com/okta and from each of them I have extracted the folders /com/okta/ and merge them in one location, for example:

okta-auth-java-master
 \api\src\main\java\   com.okta.authn.sdk
 \impl\src\main\java\   com.okta.authn.sdk.impl

okta-commons-java-master
 \config-check\src\main\java\  com.okta.commons.configcheck
 \lang\src\main\java\   com.okta.commons.lang

And so on. The .zips contain .java files, not .jar files. But each time I add .java files, some dependencies are fixed but then new are missing.

Comment: I have tried using Maven: Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Project -> Then select the root pom.xml of the project. But the project it's imported at the same level that in my project.    

And I see that only 2 or 3 files are included after the project was imported using Maven, and no one of them were Java files (that would fix the missing dependencies). No errors on Maven import.

Comment: So if your project is a maven project you dont need to import the project just add the dependencies (as described in getting started: here https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-java) to your pom file.  If your project isint a maven project you will need to download the dependencies from maven central and make sure the jars are on the class path.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gavin, I re-created the project as Maven, as it was not properly converted to Maven my former project (I am very new to Java). I included the entries for okta-auth-java and now the .jars are properly included.  Now the function that I want to use, I do not how to pass the last parameter :(      The method authenticate(String, char[], String, AuthenticationStateHandler) in the type AuthenticationClient is not applicable for the arguments (String, char[], String, String)

Comment: That would be because `AuthenticationStateHandler` isint a `String` looking at error the fourth parameter required is a `String`

Comment: Thank you Gavin, It was necessary to implement the interface and pass it as a parameter, learnt something new again. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Gavin: So if your project is a maven project you dont need to import the project just add the dependencies (as described in getting started: here github.com/okta/okta-auth-java) to your pom file. If your project isint a maven project you will need to download the dependencies from maven central and make sure the jars are on the class path.